# How do I make the row and column labels visible all the time in Numbers?

Tags: macos, iwork-numbers

For instance,
[row and column labels are visible *ONLY* if you click on the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzHJx.png)

But if you click off of the spreadsheet, [they vanish.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85pXD.png)

I do not see a setting to show the row/column labels all the time. Is there a way to make them visible, all the time?

Comment: this question seems to be missing any reference to what application, gSheets? MsExcell?

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the table.
2. In the Format  sidebar, click the Table tab, then
3. Freeze header rows and columns: Click the pop-up menus below Headers & Footer, then choose Freeze Header Rows or Freeze Header Columns.

Comment: Src: https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers/add-or-remove-rows-and-columns-tan504013a74/mac

Comment: Doing this then clicking off the table results in the same behavior as before. No difference.

Comment: This did not work for me either

Comment: What application, gSheets or msExcell?